# How to create an Average of a Measure based on a Dimension in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create an average of a measure based on a dimension without showing the dimension itself in the visualization. Here's an example.
Cases ordered has detail pp, I want just a single cell with the value 2363, which is the average of the detail column values.

[image: Window Average]

I'm not sure if this matters but PP refers to pay period which is a 2 week period, and Cases ordered is a daily value.

I tried the following with no success:

```
SUM([Nbr of Cases Ordered]) /COUNTD([pp])

{FIXED [pp]: AVG([Nbr of Cases Ordered])}

WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Nbr of Cases Ordered]))
```

Comment: change FIXED to EXCLUDE

Comment: Thank you for responding but it yields a value of 208. But stays constant when pp is removed. I'll troubleshoot further.

Comment: The behavior of a EXCLUDE LOD calc depends on the details of what other fields are on which shelves. Or you can be specific with a FIXED LOD calc. Show the rest of some data and fields involved if you want more detailed input